# Are Redux action creators hot-reloadable while using redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, flux, redux

I think they are not, but I might be missing something. My concern is that there is quite lot of potentially hot-reloadable code within action creators yet because action creator (while using thunk-middleware) may contain potentially impure operations it's not possible to hot-reload them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use React Hot Loader they should hot reload fine. If you use React Transform they currently don’t hot reload because RT doesn’t hot reload module exports, and `connect()`ed component is an export. We plan to solve this eventually, but for now, you can use React Hot Loader.

Comment: Understood, but let's just imagine there is an API call in the action creator, something like this:

```const fooActionCreator = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  if (getState().condition) {
    dispatch({type: 'AJAX_STARTED'});
  }

  $.ajax().then(() => dispatch({type: 'AJAX_FINISHED'}));
}``` then it seems to me that hot-reload (and replay) can't work because that would re-trigger the API call inside the action creator which is not idempotent operation.

Comment: @TomášWeiss Replay works on vanilla "resolved" action objects. So only "final" plain object actions will be replayed.

Comment: Excellent answer! I should have formulate the question differently because the question was not about hot-reloading but rather about replaying after hot-reloading.